# Comparing two Strings in SharedPreference

Tags: android

i set a shared preference variable:

```
SharedPreferences SPrefs;
SPrefs.edit().putString("SomeStringVariable", "sometext").commit();
```

and then i retrieve it:

```
String test1 = SPrefs.getString("SomeStringVariable", "Empty");
```

then compare it:

```
if(test1 == "sometext")
Toast.makeText(Main_Activity.this, test1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast not works , it means test1 != "sometext"
but if i remove "if" statement:

```
Toast.makeText(Main_Activity.this, test1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast Works and "sometext" appears in emulator!

why this Occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
 if(test1.equals("sometext"))
```

use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings because `==` checks fro reference equality.

Reference :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: because == checks for references equality

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(test1.equals("sometext")){
  //Toast goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string so you should use .equals not ==

So as Raghunandan said you should use

```
if(test1.equals("sometext")) instead of 
if(test1 == "sometext")  replace this line with above and you are done.
```